# Layout help needed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In the below linear layout, how can I get the image for the first ImageView to be aligned to the left...

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ABABAB"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:contentDescription="Button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:contentDescription="Button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Have tried to do it various ways, but no success so far. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the `scaleType` is causing your images to be centered, even though the views may line up. To fix this, Just set the `scaleType` attribute for both:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead of :take relative layout for it

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/id1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ABABAB"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="Button"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:contentDescription="Button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

      <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:contentDescription="Button"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```